# Perl regular expression for matching a numeric literal

Tags: regex, perl

I'm looking for a regular expression in Perl that match all the following:

```
12345
12345.67
.23E-10             # A very small number
3.14_15_92          # A very important number
4_294_967_296       # Underscore for legibility
0xff                # Hex
0xdead_beef         # More hex
0377                # Octal (only numbers, begins with 0)
0b011011            # Binary
```

My current regex is `([\d\.a-z_A-Z-]*)`, but I match too much stuff...

**Update**

I have a regular expression for each one, but I want to mix them in one.

`(\d*)`

`(\d*(?:(?=\d*)\.\d*))`

`(\d*(?:(?=\d*)\.\d*)(?:E?(?=[-|\d]*)-?\d*))`

`(\d*\.?(?:\d{0,3}_?)*)`

`(0x([a-zA-Z]*_?)*)`

`((?:\d*[a-zA-Z]*)*)`

Comment: I updated my post, I didn't put what I'm doing because I know it's not correct. I've try many different things before asking.. ^^

Comment: asking solution is gud thing, but asking and understanding whats wrong with your solution is even better practice..keep that in mind always!! :)

Comment: Do not try match them all at once, try to match each different kind with a different regual expression would be much easier.

Comment: Updated my answer, I know my regex doesn't fit all cases. Working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally ended up with the following regex :

```
\b((?:0x[a-zA-Z_]+)|(?:0[a-zA-Z\d]+)|(?:\d*\.?\d*E\-?\d*)|(?:\d*\.(?:\d{0,3}_?)*)|(?:\d+)|(?:\d*\.\d+))\b
```

I'm sure it's not perfect but it does the job.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`Regexp::Common`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp%3a%3aCommon) and specifically [`Regexp::Common::number`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp%3a%3aCommon%3a%3anumber).  It will have solutions for most of those.

```
use Regexp::Common qw /number/;

while (<>) {
    /^$RE{num}{int}$/                and  print "Integer\n";
    /^$RE{num}{real}$/               and  print "Real\n";
    /^$RE{num}{real}{-base => 16}$/  and  print "Hexadecimal real\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I can only use modules installed on my computer. :(